# Regex to match url not for certain file types

Tags: asp.net, .net, regex

I want my Regex to match all valid *URLs* that do not end with

> .gif
>   .jpg
>   .jpeg
>   .pdf
>   .doc

I tried

```
http(s)?://([\w-]+\.)+[\w-]+(/[\w- ./?%&=;]*)?((?!jpg)|(?!gif)|(?!doc))
```

Comment: This is not a "we make your work" site. What did you try and what problems you have?

Comment: @elshenawy000 - welcome to Stack Overflow. Please *read* the FAQ on how to post questions. You need to show what you've tried or, in the least, what you've looked into. People will help you - they will not simply do the work for you. The idea would be most unreasonable.

Comment: i tried the _lookahead_ regex option and faild  http(s)?://([\w-]+\.)+[\w-]+(/[\w- ./?%&=;]*)?((?!jpg)|(?!gif)|(?!doc)) and so on for all the types

Comment: the lookahead matches any url not only those that not contains the unwanted types i'm using dot net code for testing and gskinner.com

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use a **lookbehind** for that, try

```
http(s)?://([\w-]+\.)+[\w-]+(/[\w- ./?%&=;]*)?(?<!jpg)(?<!gif)(?<!doc)$
```

You need also the anchor `$` at the end, it matches the end of the string, that is important to define clearly the point from where the lookbehind should look behind.

See it [here on Regexr](http://regexr.com?31dkb)