# Need to write a java regex expression which matches urls with http or https but does not contains specific file extensions

Tags: java, regex, expression, regex-negation

I need to create a java regex expression which matches URLS with http or https but should not match urls with specific file extensions.

I can get the urls with http or https using the following expression and I am unable to complete the 2nd part that is eliminating urls with certain extensions (eg:- js|css|jpg etc..)
I guess I need to use negations but I am not sure how to do it.

`String regex = "\\s*(?i)(http|https)\\s*://\\s*((\"[^\"]*\"|'[^']*'|([^'\">\\s]+)))";`

Please help me to modify this regex to meet this requirement.

Comment: Javascript is not the same as Java. I fixed that for you. (People confuse the two a lot; Javascript is for website design.)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bregex%5D+url

Comment: possible duplicate of [regex problem with url](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2987263/regex-problem-with-url)

Comment: The link is not what I really required in this particular question.Thanks

Answer (score 1):

An easy way to implement this in Java is to use the `Pattern` class (from `java.util.regex`). To accomplish what you're suggesting, you could use two separate regex objects to check the conditions for the URL. For example (using the string `regex` from your question):

```
Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
String input = in.nextLine();
Pattern one = Pattern.compile(regex);
Pattern two = Pattern.compile("([^\s]+(\.(?i)(js|css|jpg|etc))$)");
if(one.matcher(input).matches() && !two.matcher(input).matches()) 
    System.out.println("It matches!");
else System.out.println("Nope!");
```

In short, using two Pattern objects makes your code more readable and easy to manage, since you're considering multiple aspects about an input string of a URL.

Comment: Hi,Thanks for the nice suggestion, but I really want to go for a single regex solution. :-) I know the requirement can be handled programmatic ally without regex or with several regex. thanks

Answer (score 1):

You need an anchor to look behind - see [regex to match url](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11290370/regex-to-match-url-not-for-certain-file-types) that should give you the expression you need.  The regex you have currently will match malformed urls with disallowed characters.
Here's a good site to check your expressions: http://www.regexplanet.com/advanced/java/index.html